# Plot percentage of factor levels in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table of use of vehicles where each record shows how many vehicles are for each kind of use.
I need to plot the percentage of vehicles for each use. Below I provide sample data:

```
use <- as.factor('private’, 'comercial', 'ambulance’, 'private’, 'comercial')
quantity <- c(2,1,4,6,1)
mydata <- data.frame(use, quantity)
```

In this case there should be private: 8, comercial: 2 and ambulance: 4
I have tried the following but I think that it counts the records and not the vehicles (private: 2, comercial: 2 and ambulance: 1)

```
 library(scales)
    library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(mydata, aes(x = factor(use))) + geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + coord_flip() +  
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

If i change the code:

```
 ggplot(mydata, aes(x = factor(use))) + geom_bar(aes(y = (quantity)/sum(quantity))) + coord_flip() +  
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

I receive this error:
Error: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indicate `stat = "identity"` in the call to `geom_bar`.

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = factor(use))) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(y = (quantity)/sum(quantity))) +
coord_flip() + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Comment: If I run it I get an empty graph and an error: Removed 2784716 rows containing missing values (position_stack). I have in total around 2840000 records and only 1 NA. What might be the reason of this error?